# PDF with multiple paragraphs from Java Itext

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I have a array of Strings as follows :-

```
String[] data = {“Sunday”,”Monday”,”Tuesday”,”Wednesday”,”Thursday”,”Friday”,”Saturday”}.
```

Now I want to write this data strings to a pdf file one below the other like :-

```
  1. Sunday
  2. Monday
  3. Tuesday
  4. Wednesday
  5. Thursday
  6. Friday
  7. Saturday.
```

I am using itext to achieve this. Below is the code snippet I am using

```
for(int i= 0; i< data.length;i++)

{

Document document=new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(directory));
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph(data[i]));
document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
document.close();
}
```

Problem :-

The pdf file which I get has only :-

7. Saturday.

Please help.

Comment: You are (re)creating the document in the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, you are creating the document in the loop. Try this:

```
Document document=new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(directory));
document.open();
for(int i= 0; i< data.length;i++)
{
  document.add(new Paragraph(data[i]));
  document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
}
document.close();
```

You might want to handle closing of the stream in case something happens.
With Java 7 or above you can achieve with this:

```
Document document=new Document();
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(directory)) {
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
  document.open();
  for(int i= 0; i< data.length;i++)
  {
    document.add(new Paragraph(data[i]));
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
  }
  //EDIT start
  document.close();
  //EDIT end
}
```

Comment: I don't think your second code snippet will work. `document.close()` writes all font dictionaries, the info dictionary and the cross-reference table to the output stream. This isn't possible if the stream is already closed. Your first example works perfectly. The stream is closed when you close the document.

Comment: Thanks! Now if `document.close()` is reached, `fos` will be closed by iText. However, if some exception occurs before `document.close()`, `fos` will be closed because of using the `try` construction. I love it!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating document in a loop and  also closing same.

make sure document is open and close only once in its lifetime.

```
try
{
   Document document=new Document();
   PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(directory));
   document.open();
   for(int i= 0; i< data.length;i++)
   {
      document.add(new Paragraph(data[i]));
      document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);    
   }
 }
finally{

document.close();
}
```

Comment: Your answer more or less says the same as the old accepted answer, doesn't it?